# How to have fixed number of labels at specific point on the screen using graphview?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am plotting real time data using Graphview library in android studio. I need to have just 3 labels which are date values as the x axis. Using `graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3)` sets it correctly to 3 at the beginning of the application, but if I reload the page later on it does not work and the date values overlap.
It needs to be like static labels but which changes with respect to the data.

Current display

[image]

Required display format

[image]